# ".gitignore" for Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

To permanently exclude specific file(s) from being compiled in Android Studio, we can add full path of the file(s) to be ignored in the following list:

```
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Compiler -> Excludes
```

But, how do we permanently exclude arbitrary file(s) from being compiled? I'd like to exclude files with certain keywords (can we use regex for this?) or specific file pattern (e.g. `.DS_STORE`).

I'm running Android Studio Version 0.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project uses Gradle, that preference won't work, because Gradle ignores those compiler settings -- we've filed bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64825 to track the suppression of preferences panels that don't apply.

To do this in Gradle, you use `exclude` statements inside your java `sourceSet` statements. By default new projects created in Android Studio don't specify a `sourceSet` because they use the implicit **src/main/java** directory, but you can override it. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:sourceSets(groovy.lang.Closure) for information on the `exclude` keyword and http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies for information on source sets in the Android Gradle plugin.

Note that this `exclude` keyword only works for the Java and resource source sets in the current version of the Android Gradle plugin; it's not implemented for other source sets like AIDL or RenderScript or JNI or Assets. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64957 to track the progress of that.

Answer (score 0):

I excludes some files in Android Studio as following.

> File (or Android Studio on Mac) -> Preferences -> File Types -> Ignore
>   Files and Folders (at the very bottom) -> put ".DS_Store;.git;*.iml;.idea;"

With this configuration everything build just fine, and there is no unnecessary files and folders in the project tree.